# setting control terminal for slave pseudo-tty at Solaris

Tags: c, linux, shell, ssh, solaris-10

I have the implementation of hooking and logging for entered command at shell for Solaris. It is released by libhook (library for hooking) and script with "Unix 98 pty" (which was made from this script implementation http://honeypots.sourceforge.net/script.c.solaris.txt)

If I start "script" from shell at logged-in ssh session everything works well and have some output of command ps. But if the script was started by libhook (during login of ssh libhooks detects that there is SHELL's call and starts script instead of SHELL) command ps has next output:

```
ps: no controlling terminal
```

If hooked logged-in session (under "script") has pid=19215 and in this case under clean (unhooked) ssh session "ps -el" shows next:

```
# ps -el
F S    UID   PID  PPID   C PRI NI     ADDR     SZ    WCHAN TTY         TIME CMD
1 T      0     0     0   0   0 SY        ?      0          ?           0:20 sched
0 S      0     1     0   0  40 20        ?    385        ? ?           0:04 init
1 S      0     2     0   0   0 SY        ?      0        ? ?           0:00 pageout
1 S      0     3     0   0   0 SY        ?      0        ? ?         142:52 fsflush
1 S      0     4     0   0   0 SD        ?      0        ? ?           0:57 vmtasks
 ......
0 S      0 19215 19211   0  40 20        ?    506        ? pts/6       0:00 sh
0 S      0 19211 19205   0  40 20        ?    881        ? pts/5       0:00 script
0 S      0 19205 19204   0  40 20        ?   1244        ? ?           0:01 sshd
0 S      0 19204 19203   0  40 20        ?    746        ? ?           0:00 sshd
0 S      0 19203     1   0  40 20        ?    603        ? ?           0:00 sshd
......
```

The structure of "script" calls next:

```
struct termios origtty, newtty;
tcgetattr(STDIN_FILENO, &origtty); // get tty modes
int master = open("/dev/ptmx", O_RDWR)); // opens master side of pseudo-tty
grantpt(master); // set the permissions on the slave
unlockpt(master); // unlock the slave.
pid = fork(); // create child for slave
```

and then at the child process there are next calls:

```
setsid();   // creates new process session
char * slavename = ptsname(master); // get slave name
int slave = open(slaveName, O_RDWR) // open the slave pseudo-tty
ioctl(slave, I_PUSH, "ptem"); // push the hardware emulation module
ioctl(slave, I_PUSH, "ldterm"); // push the line discipline module
tcsetattr(slave, TCSANOW, & ttymodes); // copy the user's terminal modes to the slave pseudo-tty
close(master); // close the the master; this are not needed in the slave.

dup2(slave, 0);
dup2(slave, 1);
dup2(slave, 2);
close(slave); // set the slave to be our standard input, output, and error output.
execl("/sbin/sh", "sh", NULL); // run shell there
```

for parent process have next calls:

```
newtty = origtty;
newtty.c_cc[VMIN] = 1;
newtty.c_cc[VTIME] = 0;
newtty.c_iflag &= ~(IGNBRK | BRKINT | PARMRK | ISTRIP | INLCR | IGNCR | ICRNL | IXON);
newtty.c_oflag &= ~OPOST;
newtty.c_lflag &= ~(ECHO | ECHONL | ICANON | ISIG | IEXTEN);
newtty.c_cflag &= ~(CSIZE | PARENB);
newtty.c_cflag |= CS8;
```

I have tried to get "controlTerm = open ("/dev/tty ", O_RDWR)" before command "setsid" and then set "ioctl (controlTerm, TIOCSCTTY, 1)" after "setsid" (get controlling terminal for previous session and set them at new) but in this case I had same behaviour and second command returns "-1" with errno=9 (Bad file number).

Same code tested under AIX and everything works well there.
How can I implement controlling terminal for a shell at slave pseudo-tty?

Comment: *logging for entered command* So you put in a keylogger?  Great, you've now given every miscreant on your systems a get-out-of-jail-free card by likely removing [non-repudiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-repudiation#In_security) from your systems.  "You can't prove that was me - you run a keylogger, so someone else could have snooped my password."  And it's trivial to defeat since it runs as the user. Garbage data can be inserted into it.  Attach to `script` process with debugger, `ftruncate( fileno( script ), 0 );` and goodbye all data. OSes provide auditing for a reason.  Use it.

Comment: Another way around your keylogger:  `scp` in a `.bashrc` file or similar that opens a [reverse shell](http://pentestmonkey.net/cheat-sheet/shells/reverse-shell-cheat-sheet).  You're also confusing knowing what a user types with knowing what a user does - that `.bashrc` file can change `PATH` so typing `ls` doesn't run `/bin/ls` but `/home/user/my/nefarious/ls`. And did you catch the possibility that your keylogger may very well log to a file that's readable by *everyone* on the system? If you can't figure that out from the code link you posted, you have no business using it.